# Dropping Columns where First Row Value is NA

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe as below

```
A   B   C
NA  2   NA
1   2   3
1   NA  3
1   2   3
```

and i want to remove columns that have NA in the first row (A,C)

```
  B  
  2  
  2   
 NA  
  2
```

how do I achieve this? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df[,!is.na(df[1,]), drop = F]

 B
1  2
2  2
3 NA
4  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some other options

Using base R

```
df[!is.na(sapply(df, `[`, 1))]
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select_if(~!is.na(.[1L]))
#   B
#1  2
#2  2
#3 NA
#4  2
```

Using `purrr` variants

```
purrr::discard(df, ~is.na(.[1L]))
purrr::keep(df, ~!is.na(.[1L]))
```